# Kitchen outlet/receptacle issue

Tags: receptacle, gfci

On the outlet of my dishwasher/disposal one of the receptacles is open hot. (I tested with a gfci tester). The disposal works in this receptacle. When I plug the disposal into the other receptacle the disposal starts running (without use of wall switch). Why does it start the disposal unit on this receptacle and not the other (open hot)? And why would open hot be used to connect outlet?

Comment: Honestly you've only scratched the surface of electrical knowledge and are doing things by rote, you need a bit more knowledge for the answer to make sense to you.  Hint: I bet it's not "open hot" when the switch is on.

Comment: Try turning the switch that turns on and off the disposal on when the outlet tester is plugged into the disposal outlet.

Answer (score 3):

Open hot is expected if that outlet is controlled by a switch (while the switch is off), which is typical of garbage disposals.

You say that in one receptacle "the disposal works" and in the other "it starts running", so I will *assume* "works" means "is controlled by the switch as expected", and that your question is just *why* this is so.

Here's what this circuit typically looks like:

[image: switched outlet]

> Note the white neutral wire is connected (by the "tab") to both top and bottom of the outlet. Also, for simplicity, this diagram doesn't show ground wires, or a neutral wire going to the switch (which is required since NEC 2011).

When the switch is open, there is no hot connected on the top outlet, hence the tester seeing 'open hot'. If you turn the switch on, you should see a normal working circuit (same on both top and bottom).